# Not getting an option to install the package Microsoft Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-8.0

As shown in the image below, the option to import the entity framework core is not visible:

[image]

In the drop down is there any other way to fix that issue. I want a way to install Microsoft Entity core framework package. The picture above is from Youtube.

In my Visual Studio, the option of install the Entity Framework Core is not visible

Comment: Hi, I posted a new answer based on Amit Mohanty's answer. If it is helpful to you, you can mark it (click the check mark to the left of the answer) so that it can help more people

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** Using NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

- Open Visual Studio:
- Open your project.
- Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.
- Run the following command: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

**Option 2:** Using the Manage NuGet Packages

- Open your project in Visual Studio.
- Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer. From the context menu, select `Manage NuGet Packages`.
- In the `NuGet Package Manager` window, click on the "Browse" tab. Type `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in the search box.
- Locate `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in the search results. Click the `Install` button to begin the installation process.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Amit Mohanty's addition:

**Option 1:** Using NuGet Package Manager Console in Visual Studio:

- Open Visual Studio:
- Open your project.
- Go to Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console.
- Run the following command: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`.

**Option 2:** Using the Manage NuGet Packages

- Open your project in Visual Studio.
- Right-click on your project in the Solution Explorer. From the context menu, select `Manage NuGet Packages`.
- In the `NuGet Package Manager` window, click on the "Browse" tab. Type `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in the search box.
- Locate `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` in the search results. Click the `Install` button to begin the installation process.

**Option 3:** Enter https://www.nuget.org/

Search entityframework core and find entityframework core

You will see the installation methods of various entityframework core nuget packages

- **.NET CLI:**

  ```
  dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 8.0.0
  ```
- **Package Manager:**

  ```
  NuGet\Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 8.0.0
  ```
- **PackageReference:**

  ```
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="8.0.0" />
  ```
- **Packet CLI:**

  ```
  paket add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 8.0.0
  ```
- **Script & Interactive：**

  ```
  #r "nuget: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, 8.0.0"
  ```
- **Cake:**

  ```
  //Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore as a Cake Addin

  #addin nuget:?package=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore&version=8.0.0

  //Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore as a Cake Tool

  #tool nuget:?package=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore&version=8.0.0
  ```